# merging a tag into a synonym'd tag creates that tag again?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms

On [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129104/how-to-find-a-vector-potential-inverse-curl) at Math.SE, one sees that it is tagged both with (multivariable-calculus) and (vector-calculus). If one clicks on the (vector-calculus) tag, one gets redirected, correctly, to the page for (multivariable-calculus), as for a long time the (vector-calculus) tag has been a synonym for (multivariable-calculus).

Problem: why does the post still contain both tags, instead of them collapsed into one?

What caused this:

1. Mark and merge (tag-2) as synonym to (tag-1).
2. Given a question tagged with (tag-1) and (tag-3), merge (tag-3) into (tag-2).

Ideal result:

1. Question is now tagged as (tag-1) only. All questions previously tagged under (tag-3) is now tagged (tag-1) instead.

Observed result:

1. Questions tagged with (tag-3) now is tagged with (tag-2), which displays as a different tag from (tag-1), but links to the same page.
2. (tag-2) now appears in the Tool panel for "new tags" as a new-tag, even though the link that it creates points to (tag-1).

Comment: I think it would be better to prevent merging into a synonym - you should always want to merge a "bad" tag into a "good" one, correct?

Comment: @Jarrod: yes. If that can be done, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) a synonym of [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1), you are not removing [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) from questions. Future questions using [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) will automatically have [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1), but that doesn't change already asked questions.
[tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) and [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1) are still two separate tags, if you make them synonym, and there are already questions using [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2).

To obtain the result you wanted to obtain, you should:

- Merge [tag-3](/questions/tagged/tag-3) with [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2)
- Merge [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) with [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1)
- Make [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) a synonym of [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1)

In your case, you just need to merge [tag-2](/questions/tagged/tag-2) with [tag-1](/questions/tagged/tag-1).

Comment: Right, but if I merge tag-3 into tag-2, isn't it just like removing tag-3 from questions, putting tag-2 to those questions. And since this happens *after* tag-2 is already merged and synonym'd with tag-1, shouldn't the newly appended tag-2 be mapped automatically to tag-1?

Comment: That happens only when tag-2 is manually added to questions after it has been made synonym of tag-1. Merging two tags is not considered manually adding tag-2.

Comment: Perhaps I should make this a feature request then?

Comment: You could make it a feature request. Automatically merging two tags that have been made synonym is not something I would prefer, though. If they have not merged the first time, maybe there is a reason they have not been merged. Consider that between step 1, and step 2 could pass even months. I would prefer the merging is made manually.

Comment: Ah! No, no, no! I think you misunderstood me. In step 1 of *my scenario* the tags are merged and synonymed already! I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: In other words, at the time tag-3 was merged into tag-2, tag-2 already _does not exist_ except as a synonym for tag-1.

Comment: You wrote "Mark (tag-2) as synonym to (tag-1)." That doesn't mean the tags have been merged.

Comment: Yes. I just realised that's what you meant with your answer. So I edited to clarify. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design: merging into a tag prevents that tag to be a non-master synonym. We don't want to create a whole graph of synonyms.

Regarding how to obtain the result you want, [kiamlaluno's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128789/131112) is the way to do it.